# Mustang V6 sluggish pickup during day

Tags: ford, power, throttle, mustang

Have been driving my stang 2013 V6  for almost 2 years now. Right from the day 1 I have noticed that outside temperature somehow made my cars acceleration/ pickup however you call it become sluggish. I feel my car is more monster at night than at day I can easily get to 80 in no time and there have been times i felt uncontrolled power thrown back at me. Am I over thinking or is it really that hottter climate affects engine speed and pickup somehow??

I was talking to a friend of mine and he said it would make more sense if it was other way around since engine gets heated quicker during day( not sure if this really is connected to the pickup part)

Is there something I can add up or install to dix this , I top up the fluids every 3 months promptly.

Comment: What are the local day vs. night temperatures where you are?  Please include the units of temperature as well - 30C and 30F are very different temps.

Comment: lols not too variant but i do feel a drag during the day time.  I always  felt a drag when accelrating so posted it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cold, humid air will make a difference. You can run richer mixture on a cold morning than on a hot afternoon, for example. On a small two-stroke you'll swap jets, while a modern (generous usage here) car adjust the mixture itself according to sensor data.

Comment: is there something I can use to fix this temperature diff the engine goes through giving me a uniform acdeleration all through!!

Answer (score 0):

Humid air will for sure make a difference, depending on exactly how hot it is where you live.

As for being able to cool the air down, there are a few different aftermarket options, but nothing that I'd reccomend. Cold-Air intakes don't make a difference. I knew of a few airboxes you can get that cool the air, but I don't have any experience with them.